# Prove expectation finite

Tags: functions, expectation

Let $ \{b_n\} $ be a sequence of non-zero  complex numbers. We have $ N(t)=\#\{n \geq 1:|b_{n}|\leq t\} $, $ \displaystyle\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty} N(t)/t^p<\infty (1\leq p <2)$, for $ X_1\in L_p(P) $ , why do we have: $ E[N(|X_1|)]<\infty $?

http://www.ee.bgu.ac.il/~guycohen/clsurvey.pdf
see also in this link, page 5, theorem 2.2

Comment: It looks like $N(t)$ is a number. Your notation $lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}supN(t)/t^p$ is unclear. Can you check your question for typos and clarity? The supremum is taken of a set. Maybe you mean: $ N(t)=\{n \geq 1:|b_{n}|\leq t\} $, $ \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \sup N(t)/t^p$? Or do you mean $ N(t)=\#\{n \geq 1:|b_{n}|\leq t\} $, $ \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} N(t)/t^p$?

Comment: http://www.ee.bgu.ac.il/~guycohen/clsurvey.pdf see also in this link, page 5, theorem 2.2

Comment: It means "lim sup"

Comment: Having the link is helpful, but it might be better to type up a bit more context for the problem here so readers don't have to sort through the pdf to figure everything out. For example, what is $b_n$?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will edit it again ^^ Can you help me?? Please

Comment: Hint: Show that there exists $C$ and $C'$ finite such that $N(t)\leqslant Ct^p+C'$ for every $t$ and apply this to bound $E(N(|X|))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $E(|X_1|^p)<\infty$ because $X_1\in L^p$ and that $N(|X_1|)=\#\{n\geq1 : |b_n|\leq|X_1|\}$. $E(N(|X_1|))=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(N(|X_1|)\geq n)$. There must exist a constant $C$ such that $N(t)\leq Ct^p$ for all $t$ sufficiently large.

Thus we get $N(|X_1|)\leq C |X_1|^p$ when $|X_1|$ takes sufficiently large values, say when $|X_1|>K$.

Let $M=\sup_{t\leq K} N(t)$. We have $N(|X_1|)\leq M$ when $|X_1|\leq K$ and that $N(|X_1|)\leq C |X_1|^p$ when $|X_1|> K$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
E(N(|X_1|)) &\leq M P(|X_1| \leq K)+C\sum_{n=K+1}^\infty n^pP(|X_1|= n)\\
&\leq M+C\cdot E(|X_1|^p) < \infty.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: "$N(|X_1|)\leq C |X_1|^p$ for all $|X_1|$ sufficiently large" is not a formulation one can accept without qualms. Please modify.

Comment: @Did, I edited the text a bit in an attempt to make it more transparent. Is it better now?

Comment: @jdods Not really. It seems you are at a loss to make use of the fact that $N(t)\leqslant Ct^p$ for some finite $C$ but only for $t\geqslant t_0$. I delineated an easy and neat way out in my comment to the main question.

Comment: @Did, ok, I finally saw the terrible abuses and inconsistencies you were referring to I believe. How about now?

Comment: This is more complicated than necessary in several places (and why "stochastically smaller" instead of "smaller"?) but yes the current solution is correct.

Comment: I guess I was thinking of the copies of $X_1$ potentially being "different trials", and I see your point. And I guess I could have completely left out the construction of $Y$. Thanks for checking so thoroughly, I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome. I see you have a PhD in theoretical ecology. What is it about (briefly...)?

Comment: Most of my recent work has been with ODE models looking at how different types of variability affect population dynamics. Liggett's Interacting Particle Systems book was my constant companion during school. I'm trying to get back into the more theoretical stuff (which as you can see, I'm quite weak at).

Comment: Thank you. I understood this.