# Prove the series converges a.s in Probability

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, expectation

I have an article as follows
[image]

***Why are they enough to prove that $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{X_n \textbf{1}_{\{|b_n|< |X_n|\}}}{b_n} $ converges almost surely? I want to know why must prove $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n|\geq |b_n|)<\infty$ to have $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{X_n \textbf{1}_{\{|b_n|\geq |X_n|\}}}{b_n} $ converges almost surely. Please help me.***

Comment: May I ask what `a.s.` means?

Comment: It means "almost surely"

Comment: Please replace `X_1` by `X_n` in the series. Even more importantly, *what do you think?* To begin with, can you adapt [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1373724/)?

Comment: I understood that. Now, I want to know why must prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P< \infty $

Comment: I know $\sum_n P(|X_n-X|>\infty)<\infty$ implies $X_n$ converges a.s to $X$. Can it apply to prove above??

Comment: could you explain why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n|\geq |b_n|)=E\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{|b_n| \leq |X_1|\}}\right] = E[N(|X_1|)]<\infty$?

Comment: Because we have $P(|X_n|\geq |b_n|)=E(\textbf{1}_{\{ |X_n| \geq |b_n|)\} })$ and $\{X_n\}$  is a sequence of independent identical distribution random variables so we replace $X_n$ by $X_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of that proof skips a lot of steps!

It seems that the author is secretly making use of the Borel-Cantelli lemma. Equation (*) shows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} Pr[|b_n|\leq |X_n|] < \infty$, which means (by Borel-Cantelli) that, with prob 1, the event $|b_n|\leq |X_n|$ only happens for a finite number of integers $n$. This also means that $|b_n|<|X_n|$ only happens for a finite number of integers $n$.

Then: I *think* this proof is trying to prove part (i), which means they want to conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_n/b_n$ converges almost surely to some (possibly random) real number as $N\rightarrow\infty$.  So you can write: 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{X_n}{b_n} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{X_n}{b_n} 1\{|b_n|<|X_n|\} + \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{X_n}{b_n}1\{|b_n|\geq|X_n|\} \: \: (Eq. **)$$
Since, with prob 1, the event $|b_n|<|X_n|$ only happens for a finite number of integers $n$, we can say there is some random $M$ such that $M$ is the last integer for which it holds. So, the first summation on the right-hand-side of (Eq. **) stays at a fixed value and never changes once $N>M$: 
$$  \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{X_n}{b_n}1\{|b_n|<|X_n|\} = \sum_{n=1}^M \frac{X_n}{b_n}1\{|b_n|<|X_n|\} $$
So the limit of the first term on the right-hand-side of (Eq. **) indeed converges almost surely as $N\rightarrow\infty$.  That is why the author is saying it is "enough" to prove that the second term on the right-hand-side *also* converges almost surely as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: You helped me understand this issue. Thank you very much!